# using boost::lambda or boost::phoenix with std::find_if

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix, boost-lambda

I have a class like this

```
class Foo {
    public:
        int GetID() const { return m_id; }
    private:
        int m_id;
};
```

I want to use find_if on a vector full of Foo objects, like this:

```
std::find_if(foos.begin(), foos.end(), ???.GetID() == 42);
```

I don't quite get what I have to write instead of ???. I know there is either _1 with boost::lambda or arg1 with boost::phoenix, but after that I'm at a loss.

**Edit:**

I tried the following which does not work, even though I saw it like this in many examples.

```
std::find_if(foos.begin(), foos.end(), boost::lambda::bind(&Foo::GetID, boost::lambda::_1) == 42);
```

Then I get the following error:

> error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const boost::lambda::lambda_functor' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: why doing it to yourself when you can use the c++11 standard?

Comment: @David Haim: I wish I could ;)

Comment: `std::find_if(foos.begin(), foos.end(), (&boost::phoenix::placeholders::_1->*&Foo::GetID)() == 42);`

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki: That gives me the error: cannot convert from 'const boost::phoenix::actor<Expr> *' to 'const Foo *'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `boost::bind` for this case, it's really the easiest way before C++11.

```
std::find_if(foos.begin(), foos.end(), boost::bind(&Foo::GetId, _1) == 42);
```

If you should use `phoenix` you can use `phoenix::bind`.

```
std::find_if(foos.begin(), foos.end(),
phx::bind(&Foo::GetId, phx::placeholders::_1) == 42);
```

where `phx` is

```
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
```

If you can use C++11 - you can use `std::bind`, or lambda function

```
std::find_if(foos.begin(), foos.end(), 
[](const Foo& f) { return f.GetId() == 42; });
```

Comment: @gartenriese you are trying wrong. In my example is just boost bind, not boost lambda bind. And look at my example, in your example there is no compare with actual value.

Comment: Oh my. If I use boost::bind instead of boost::lambda::bind, it works. Thanks a lot, I'd never guessed!

Comment: The `phoenix` version does not work like you explained though.

Comment: @gartenriese work as well. Look: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e027c53f781ff63

Comment: Huh, now it works. I must've forgotten some headers. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure `boost::bind(...)==42`  would work. Does it overload `==` ?

Comment: @Nawaz yep. `boost::bind` has all compare operators overloaded. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html#operators